# HTML Content Overflowing the Page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im working on a small site and I've encountered a problem where my website content overflows a little off the page by about 100px.

I want my content to not overflow where the user will have to always scroll to the right to see all of the content.

I have included a snippet of code here that I have made to replicate the problem. I have tried using the overflow property but it doesnt seem to change my result.

It may be the image I am using on my site (which I cant post here), but maybe thats too wide? I'm not sure why the content is overflowing all of a sudden. Thanks for any help!

```css
.body
{
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-wrapper
{
  display: flex;
}

.image_div
{
  flex: 1;
}

.text_div
{
  flex: 1;
}

#image
{
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<div class="flex-wrapper">
<div class="image_div">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" id="image">
</div>

<div class="text_div">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: overflow-y hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should remove that dot in `.body {` and leave it just `body {` since if you put `.body` you're giving the css to a body class and you're not using any class named body and about you having a scrollbar on y axis.

I think you could use a viewport dimensions, adjust your div's to your screen and hide the overflow on y, but to make it more easy for you to understand check the code below

```css
body
{
  width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.flex-wrapper
{
  display: flex;
  height:80vh;
}

.image_div
{
  flex: 1;
}

.text_div
{
  flex: 1;
  height:70%;
}

#image
{
  width: 70%;
height:70%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div style="height:20vh;"><p style="height:80%;overflow:auto">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>

<div class="flex-wrapper">
<div class="image_div">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" id="image">
</div>

<div class="text_div">
<p style="height:50%;overflow:auto;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

NOTE : The viewport work is a percentage of your screen with this i mean you have to divide your screen until reaching 100, on the example i gave you the top paragraph has 40% of the screen and the image and other text has 60% of the screen

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it seems to work well, thanks fro explaining :)

Comment: You're welcome, i am glad i could help, if you need help with anything about this just tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#img {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto; 
}
```

or

```
.flex-wrapper
{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```